# initialize & start NSThread with target & selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread

I have a function which takes a block as parameter:

```
typedef void (^ MyCallBack)(int);

-(void)doTask:(MyCallBack)callback{
 ...
}
```

I need to run the function in another thread with `NSThread`:

```
NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                             selector:@selector(doTask:)
                                               object:nil]; //how to pass callback block here?
[myThread start];
```

But how can I have the callback passed in the NSThread initialisation function above? Is it possible?

(If it is impossible, what could be the good alternative to achieve the same?)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10247055/5109911

Comment: I can't seem t understand your issue, you are trying to pass the block as the "object" param of NSThrad initialization? the object is from "id" type, you can pass anything you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930228/pass-block-as-parameter-in-my-case/38933171#38933171). This is the way to proceed I think you have asked the same question twice